# Using .BY with a lookup table--unexpected results

Tags: r, data.table

I'd like to create a variable in `dt` according to a lookup table `k`.  I'm getting some unexpected results depending on how I extract the variable of interest in `k`.

```
dt <- data.table(x=c(1:10))
setkey(dt, x)

k <- data.table(x=c(1:5,10), b=c(letters[1:5], "d"))
setkey(k, x)

dt[,b:=k[.BY, list(b)],by=x]

dt  #unexpected results
#      x  b
#  1:  1  1
#  2:  2  2
#  3:  3  3
#  4:  4  4
#  5:  5  5
#  6:  6  6
#  7:  7  7
#  8:  8  8
#  9:  9  9
# 10: 10 10

dt <- data.table(x=c(1:10))
setkey(x, x)

dt[,b:=k[.BY]$b,by=x]

dt  #expected results
#      x  b
#  1:  1  a
#  2:  2  b
#  3:  3  c
#  4:  4  d
#  5:  5  e
#  6:  6 NA
#  7:  7 NA
#  8:  8 NA
#  9:  9 NA
# 10: 10  d
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use `by=.` here at all.

## First solution:

Set appropriate keys and use X[Y] syntax from `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(x=c(1:10))
setkey(dt, "x")
k <- data.table(x=c(1:5,10), b=c(letters[1:5], "d"))
setkey(k, "x")

k[dt]

#      x  b
#  1:  1  a
#  2:  2  b
#  3:  3  c
#  4:  4  d
#  5:  5  e
#  6:  6 NA
#  7:  7 NA
#  8:  8 NA
#  9:  9 NA
# 10: 10  d
```

OP said that this creates a new data.table and it is undesirable for him.

## Second solution

Again, without `by`:

```
dt <- data.table(x=c(1:10))
setkey(dt, "x")
k <- data.table(x=c(1:5,10), b=c(letters[1:5], "d"))
setkey(k, "x")

# solution
dt[k, b := i.b]
```

This does not create a new `data.table` and gives the solution you're expecting.

## To explain why the unexpected result happens:

**For the first case** you do, `dt[,b:=k[.BY, list(b)],by=x]`. Here, `k[.BY, list(b)]` itself returns a `data.table`. For example:

```
k[list(x=1), list(b)]

#    x b
# 1: 1 a
```

So, basically, if you would do:

```
k[list(x=dt$x), list(b)]
```

That would give you the desired solution as well. To answer why you get what you get when you do `b := k[.BY, list(b)]`, since, the RHS returns a `data.table` and you're assigning a variable to it, it takes the first element and drops the rest. For example, do this:

```
dt[, c := dt[1], by=x] 
# you'll get the whole column to be 1
```

**For the second case**, to understand why it works, you'll have to know the subtle difference between, accessing a `data.table` as `k[6]` and `k[list(6)]`, for example:

In the first case, `k[6]`, you are accessing the 6th element of `k`, which is `10 d`. But in the second case, you're asking for a `J, join`. So, it searches for x = 6 (key column) and since there isn't any in `k`, it returns `6 NA`. In your case, since you use `k[.BY]` which returns a list, it is a `J` operation, which fetches the right value.

I hope this helps.

Comment: That creates an entirely new data table which my method avoids. Additionally, I'm particularly interested in why the results depend on how I extract `b` from `k`

Comment: First, `.BY` returns a list. So, you'll have to access `k[.BY$x, b]`. Actually, you can just access it as `k[x, b]`. I'm figuring out the other reason and how to get the solution as you require.

Comment: `k[x,b]`, I believe, would not be as efficient in the case where there are a large number of rows in each by group.

Comment: Nope, it would be, if you set the key of `k` to be `x`. That's the idea of a key.

Comment: +10! I didn't know about the 'taking the first element and dropping the rest' bit. Seems like data.table could do with a new warning in that case?

Comment: @MatthewDowle, Thank you. But this happens when `by=(key)` is used. And it's the same for even a vector. For ex: `dt <- data.table(x=1:10); setkey(dt, "x"); y <- 1:10; dt[, b := y, by=x];` will again result in `b=1` all over. `y` being a vector and being assigned to a variable the first element is *silently* assigned. I suppose a warning in case of `:=` when RHS doesn't match the type of LHS would be useful, for sure!

Comment: @Arun, great explanation!  as for the last comment though, i dont think it necessarily has to do with `by=(key)`. Rather, it simply due to recycling combined with the assignment taking the first element of the vector.   eg: `dt <- data.table(x=1:10, z=1:10); setkey(dt, "x");  dt[,  y, by=z];`

Comment: @MatthewDowle, that could be a helpful warning :)    Incidentally, the warnings in data.table are pretty great all around

Comment: Thanks all, will take a look. Filed as [#2588](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2588&group_id=240&atid=975).